# Search Tweets in Spreadsheet - Google App Script

Tags: search, twitter, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to store tweets in a spreadsheet from specific searches on Twitter using Google App Script. Do you know how can I make the tweets to appear in the Spreadsheet? The id call for the query function and the API authentication are (I guess) correctly set, but the results for specifics queries are not pull into the sheet. This is part of the code following [this guide](http://ctrlq.org/code/19963-twitter-followers-script):

```
 // Authenticate Twitter API requests with the bearer token
 var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='+q;

 var apiOptions = {
   headers : {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
   },
   "method" : "get"
 };  
 var responseApi = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, apiOptions); 

 var result = "";
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var cell = ss.getRange('C3');

 if (responseApi.getResponseCode() == 200) {
 var tweets = JSON.parse(responseApi.getContentText());
 return tweets.statuses;  
 }

 var row = 0;
 while(result.next()) {
   for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {     // four fields per record
      cell.offset(row, i).setValue(result.getString(i+1));
   }
   row++;
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can consider using the [Twitter Archiver add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-archiver/pkanpfekacaojdncfgbjadedbggbbphi?hl=en) that saves tweets in a Google Sheet (disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: your code is confusing, you declared result as empty string, then in `if` condition you have returned tweets.statuses so code below is unreachable if condition is true. if `if` condition fails then result contains empty string so nothing will get written

Comment: @MShoaib91 Thanks for the tip. I will tri it.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal Thank you, Amit. I know your great app and blog, but I was trying to write my own solution for customization purposes.

Comment: I've found a good solution here:  http://videlais.com/2015/03/09/collecting-tweets-using-google-scripts-part-1/ Thanks